# ImageIO.write doesn't work with jpg

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I'm using this to write an image:

```
String fileURL = Context.getContext().gets("appPath") + "upload/tmp/" + i + ".jpg";
ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) img, "jpg", new File(fileURL));
```

It works on my computer, but not on the server. On the server, `ImageIO.write` returns `false`.

Also, if I run `ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName()`, the returned list doesn't contain `jpg` in it.

I can write the image with `png` format, but I need it in `jpg`.

Comment: What Java version (and of which vendor) are you running on the server? According to the [ImageIO API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html), all implementations are supposed to support reading and writing of jpg files.

Comment: JVM Version: 1.8.0_121-8u121-b13-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b13, JVM Vendor: Oracle Corporation

Comment: You're saying you're missing `com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter`?

Comment: This is what I get after I loop ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName():   bmp
 BMP
 gif
GIF
WBMP
png
 PNG
 wbmp

Comment: There is no zero argument version of that method. What does `ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg")` return?

Comment: This: `javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageWriterIterator@393ada1d`

Comment: What's *inside* the iterator?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a complete beginner with Java. Is this what you're asking me? `Iterator test = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg");` followed by `while (test.hasNext()) {
       Log.log("content: " + test.next());
      }`. This loop is empty, nothing is logged

Comment: I didn't realize it's possible to install the JDK without all the default image support, but it seems you've managed to do that. Well, maybe you can install the Java Advanced Imaging (JAI) plugin and sort it out with that.

Comment: Could it be a bug in that particular JRE build (ie: did you try a different version)? Or a known bug in the JRE on this platform? As @Jesper already pointed out, JPEG support isn't optional, it is a *requirement* for implementations of the  javax.imageio API.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your server does not have X11 running. This is a Java (AWT/Java2D) issue.